# Get Bert Embeddings for every Token in a Sentence

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp, data-science

I have a dataframe in python in which i have a column of textual data. I need to run a loop where i would take each row in that textual column and get the bert embedding for every token in that particular row. I then need to append those vector embeddings and try it out for some purpose.

e.g " My name is Obama"
get 768 vector embedding for 'My'
get 768 vector embedding for 'name'
get 768 vector embedding for 'is'
get 768 vector embedding for 'Obama'

final output: vector embedding of size 768*4 = 3072
assume every row has exact number of words present

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are trying to bring contextual based embedding for individual words of a sentence into picture, instead of fixed vectors like that of GloVe.
Your approach should be.

1. Tokenize your paragraphs into individual sentences ( look at some sentence tokenizers or SBD (sentence boundary detection) methods if applicable)
2. Now for each of the Sentence which constitute a paragraph, get the embedding for words.
3. Average that across so that you get vectors of consistent shapes across multiple paragraps (in your case dataframe cell - which is essentially paragraphs)

`pip install sentence-transformers`

once installed;

```
model = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-distilroberta-base-v1')

#Our sentences we like to encode
sentences = ['This framework generates embeddings for each input sentence',
    'Sentences are passed as a list of string.',
    'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.']

#Sentences are encoded by calling model.encode()
embeddings = model.encode(sentences)

#Print the embeddings
for sentence, embedding in zip(sentences, embeddings):
    print("Sentence:", sentence)
    print("Embedding:", embedding)
    print("")
```

look at the embedding vector and aggregation techniques around embeddings.

Comment: This will also give me 768 vector embeddings for every sentence. I was hoping to get 768 vector embedding for every word. Is there any way to do it using bert?

Comment: Look again this will give you 768 * n vector . where n is the number of words in sentence.

Comment: @IamKarim1992 I don't understand how this gives 768 * number of words. each sentence gives you an embedding of size 768. So you'll just have three embeddings in this case.

Comment: It is size (768,). It does not break down by words.